# Access Control for Google Cloud Logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-logging, role-based-access-control

I am trying to maintain access control for google cloud logging.

For example, I have a compute engine VM, inside which multiple applications are running inside an OpenShift cluster e.g. application 1, application 2 etc. I want to send these application specific logs to log buckets.

Is it possible, that people who are working on application 1 in VM can only see logs specific to application 1, whereas people working on application 2 in VM can only see logs specific to application 2.

Condition - same VM, different applications, people see logs only for the applications they are working on.

My approach is to create log views then control access based on bucket level access and field level access. Is it possible to do in this way?

Please suggest any other solution if available, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi `raj` this [official document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-views#add_users) from google will help you in configuring access based log views. Since all your logs are being generated from the same VM you can add custom variables or user defined values in your log files using which you can create a filter for your log views

Comment: Hi @KranthiveerDontineni thanks for your response. Would it however fulfill this criteria - "people who are working on application 1 in VM can only see logs specific to application 1, whereas people working on application 2 in VM can only see logs specific to application 2".

Comment: Yes @raj it will fulfill them as we are providing access to log views using IAM, you can specify which IAM user can access which log view

Comment: Thanks @KranthiveerDontineni, let me try with this.

Comment: Hi `Raj` have you tried the solution provided by me, do you still have some queries..?

Comment: Hi @KranthiveerDontineni, yes I tried with the log views for logs coming from a single VM, the separation worked properly as expected. Next would be to try with custom LOG_ID values and then place the same access control. That would complete my use case. Many thanks.